# What is the best way to access a CacheContainer bean (defined in JBOSS EAP 6.4.0) through a Camel route

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, infinispan

I am investigating the usage of caching in Jboss EAP. Here is what my application stack looks like: 
JBOSS EAP 6.4.0
JBOSS Fuse 6.3.0
Camel (2.17.0) comes with Fuse.

The steps that I have followed: 
- Defined a Cache Container and Default Cache (local) using the JBoss EAP Administration Console. 
- Defined a Java class (CacheHelper) that looks up the Cache Container like this:

```
public DefaultCacheContainer defaultCacheContainer;
this.defaultCacheContainer = 
            (DefaultCacheContainer)    InitialContext.doLookup("java:jboss/infinispan/container/myCacheContainer");
```

- I am trying to access this Cache Container using the Apache Camel expression

The behavior that I see is as follows: 
- The Java object fetched by the JNDI lookup is of type org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCacheContainer. 
- I am unable to set a Bean reference for the cache container retrieved from JBoss EAP in the Camel expression above.

Is there a way we can access the DefaultCacheContainer returned by the lookup from within the Camel route? 
My current situation is that I cannot use the Camel expression since the bean definition is not available in the registry.

Do you think there is a way to do so?

Comment: The CAmel expression mentioned above was <to id="_to2" uri="infinispan://localhost?cacheContainer=#cacheHelper.defaultCacheContainer"/> I would like to have a way to pass the looked up Cache Container to the Camel Infinispan endpoint

Comment: Have you tried to send a request to Red Hat support? Red Hat provides professional support for EAP.